# Query to find number Rows attach to each id

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Need to find the number of rows each id have and add the number_of_id column to the table. I used the following code, the error is " Ambiguous column name user_id". Any solutions?

Original table

```
user_id         product_name       release_year
----------      -------------      ------------
id1             nameA              2012
id2             nameB              2004
id1             nameC              2008
id3             nameC              2012
id4             nameD              2016
```

Desired table

```
user_id         product_name       release_year    number_of_id
----------      -------------      ------------    -------------
id1             nameA              2012            2         
id2             nameB              2004            1
id1             nameC              2008            2
id3             nameC              2012            1
id4             nameD              2016            1
```

SQL queries:

```
SELECT 
    user_id,
    product_name,
    release_year,
    COUNT(user_id)as number_of_id
FROM (
  SELECT  
    user_id,
    product_name,
    release_year,
    user_id
  FROM
    [my path:only have one table]    
  GROUP BY  
    user_id,
    user_id ) x
  GROUP BY  
    user_id,
    product_name,
    release_year;
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: You select and group by user_id twice in your definition of x. Might that be it?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name BigQuery

Comment: @GordonLinoff edited.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to do what you want:

```
select t.*, count(*) over (partition by user_id) as cnt
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error appear because your sub select has 2 or more columns with same name, in this case "user_id", you need create alias for one of them.

Or if you have multiples tables in "[my path]" you can create alias for them.

```
    SELECT 
    user_id,
    product_name,
    release_year,
    COUNT(user_id)as number_of_id
FROM (
  SELECT  
    user_id,
    product_name,
    release_year,
    user_id as user_id2
  FROM
    [my path]    
  GROUP BY  
    user_id,
    user_id ) x
  GROUP BY  
    user_id,
    product_name,
    release_year;
```